# AngularJS:How can i change value of the ng-class ternary operator as per the controller scope?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angular-directive

I have the below scope variable in my directive's controller and my scope get evaluated the value for the variable as weekday or weekend. If it is weekday, i need to set the css class `.weekDay`to the div and if it is weekend, i need to set the css class as `.weekEnd`. The below Ternary expression which i have used in my directive is not working for me? What is the wrong over here and can i evaluate my controller expression with in the ng-class? Kindly help.

```
$scope.toDay = "Monday";
 or 
$scope.toDay ="Sunday"


<div ng-class="{toDay=='Sunday'? 'weekEnd':'weekDay'}">
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the comparison operator `===` so your code should look as follows

```
<div ng-class="toDay === 'Sunday' ? 'weekEnd' : 'weekDay'">
```

Comment: sorry. i have tried with today == 'sunday' but it was not worked. let me try your suggestion ===. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

```
<div ng-class="[today === 'Sunday' ? 'weekend' : 'weekday']">
```

note the `[]` instead of `{}` & `===` instead of `=`.

Comment: you don't, actually. you can pass either a string/string variable, a map (```{}```), or an array of the strings and/or map. The link you attached actually explains this.

Comment: and using ```{}``` in this case does not work because ```{today === 'Sunday' ? 'weekend' : 'weekday'}``` doesn't really evaluate into a valid javascript object.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$scope.toDay = "Monday";
 or 
$scope.toDay ="Sunday"


<div class="{{toDay==='Sunday'? 'weekEnd':'weekDay'}}">
```

Comment: In ng-class not possible use ternary operator.

"Expression to eval. The result of the evaluation can be a string representing space delimited class names, an array, or a map of class names to boolean values. In the case of a map, the names of the properties whose values are truthy will be added as css classes to the element."

Comment: it is possible to use the ternary operator with `ng-class`. See here https://scotch.io/tutorials/the-many-ways-to-use-ngclass

Comment: Good! But you need use without "{ ... }" ( Expression )

See example: 

<div ng-class="$variableToEvaluate ? 'class-if-true' : 'class-if-false'"></div>

Answer (score 0):

You actually don't really need to use a Tertiary operator, you could just refactor a little and use...

```
<div ng-app ng-init="toDay = 'Monday'">
<h1 ng-class="{'weekEnd': toDay == 'Sunday', 'weekDay' : toDay != 'Sunday'}">
      Test Text
  </h1>
</div>
```

Or some comparison along those lines